# visjs graph2d showMinorLines example

Tags: vis.js

I want to hide the horizontal major/minor lines that appear on Graph2D Y-axis values of a scatter plot/timeline.

I have tried to make use of showMinorLines and showMajorLines without much success. The syntax am using is:

```
graph2d.setOptions({showMinorLines: false})
```

However, it generates an error that states:

> Unknown option detected: "showMinorLines". Did you mean
>   "showMinorLabels"?
>
> Problem value found at:  options = {   showMinorLines }
>
> vis.js:23607 Errors have been found in the supplied options object.

Any help would be much appreciated?

Update: Attaching image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up. This is an fault in the documentation: in v4, this option has been renamed to get a more consistent API. You now have the following four related options:

```
{
  showMinorLabels: true | false,    // minor labels and lines on horizontal axis
  showMajorLabels: true | false,    // major labels and lines on horizontal axis
  dataAxis: {
    showMinorLabels: true | false,  // minor labels and lines on vertical axis
    showMajorLabels: true | false,  // major labels and lines on vertical axis
  }
}
```

We will fix the docs, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is around hiding the horizontal lines (pls refer attached image).

Comment: Red the code snippet you have mentioned (read the comments too); tried it as well. It works for eliminating the labels not the lines for me. Is it the version issue? Am using 4.9 from the CDN.

Comment: hm, you're right. Seems that this option was removed, I don't know why. I've opened an issue for this: https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1365